# Making text to bold in rich text box in windows forms

Tags: c#

how to bold text using rich text box and button? got error when doing this

```
private void italic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily,Font.Size, Font.Bold);
        }
```

**Error :**

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Drawing.Font.Font(System.Drawing.FontFamily, float,
>   System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Drawing.Font.Font(System.Drawing.FontFamily, float, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change **Font.Bold** to **FontStyle.Bold**.

Change it like this

```
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
```